# Agora cloud recording is not saving file in S3 when streaming from android

Tags: agora.io

I have already viewed this question
I followed the procedure, first called acquire then start then stop

I followed the procedure , first called acquire then start then stop

Here is my acquire call
 `https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/{{APPID}}/cloud_recording/acquire`

Request body

```
{
  "cname": "{{AccessChannel}}",
  "uid": "{{RecordingUID}}",
  "clientRequest":{
  }
}
```

The response

```
{
    "resourceId": "nUwUbQf9Zg6tsgtLslGnDg0lk8RYaUE09pqOuSIgwfzZ8g-RNe4wP9vsFnBhU785sHbxN0_dI8MVBqLWrCy7TCUo4U3XXne-2hA7expaSg-NgpZ5PcnFK-IrNSvmFNJqL4PGS9hw2q7lDYEtJH_0VgBG4Qdsg2TofWuF2DW7IMAt8NYBp9Hh_06d1K3pIcMJFPUWvfV7fInPDrecYuDmZdiRS9AYydjQlHa6jb51S0sKXzTVYELCJZAXP-ALS_whAh_ojFeltKLKzOC9iYodyAAwq4QnclbL3LKvBeVtCEfS9WjyYzyHDhCngJ-JrIwW"
}
```

Then I call start

URL :  [https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/{{APPID}}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{{resourceId}}/mode/mix/start](https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/%7B%7BAPPID%7D%7D/cloud_recording/resourceid/%7B%7BresourceId%7D%7D/mode/mix/start)

Body:

```
{
   "cname":"{{AccessChannel}}",
   "uid":"{{RecordingUID}}",
   "clientRequest":{
      "recordingConfig":{
         "maxIdleTime":300,
         "streamTypes":2,
         "channelType":1,
         "videoStreamType":0,
         "transcodingConfig":{
            "height":640,
            "width":360,
            "bitrate":500,
            "fps":15,
            "mixedVideoLayout":1,
            "backgroundColor":"#FF0000"
         },
         "subscribeVideoUids":[
            "123",
            "456"
         ],
         "subscribeAudioUids":[
            "123",
            "456"
         ],
         "subscribeUidGroup":0
      },
      "storageConfig":{
         "vendor":1,
         "region":0,
         "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
         "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
         "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}",
         "fileNamePrefix":[
            "directory1",
            "directory2"
         ]
      },
      "recordingFileConfig":{
         "avFileType":[
            "hls"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "resourceId": "nUwUbQf9Zg6tsgtLslGnDg0lk8RYaUE09pqOuSIgwfzZ8g-RNe4wP9vsFnBhU785sHbxN0_dI8MVBqLWrCy7TCUo4U3XXne-2hA7expaSg-NgpZ5PcnFK-IrNSvmFNJqL4PGS9hw2q7lDYEtJH_0VgBG4Qdsg2TofWuF2DW7IMAt8NYBp9Hh_06d1K3pIcMJFPUWvfV7fInPDrecYuDmZdiRS9AYydjQlHa6jb51S0sKXzTVYELCJZAXP-ALS_whAh_ojFeltKLKzOC9iYodyAAwq4QnclbL3LKvBeVtCEfS9WjyYzyHDhCngJ-JrIwW",
    "sid": "6068aec4fd4fc47b623bceaf1f2c8f6b"
}
```

And finally I called stop

URL: [https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/{{APPID}}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{{resourceId}}/sid/{{sid}}/mode/mix/stop](https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/%7B%7BAPPID%7D%7D/cloud_recording/resourceid/%7B%7BresourceId%7D%7D/sid/%7B%7Bsid%7D%7D/mode/mix/stop)

Body:

```
{
  "cname": "{{AccessChannel}}",
  "uid": "{{RecordingUID}}",
  "clientRequest": {}
}
```

And the response is

```
{
    "resourceId": "nUwUbQf9Zg6tsgtLslGnDg0lk8RYaUE09pqOuSIgwfzZ8g-RNe4wP9vsFnBhU785sHbxN0_dI8MVBqLWrCy7TCUo4U3XXne-2hA7expaSg-NgpZ5PcnFK-IrNSvmFNJqL4PGS9hw2q7lDYEtJH_0VgBG4Qdsg2TofWuF2DW7IMAt8NYBp9Hh_06d1K3pIcMJFPUWvfV7fInPDrecYuDmZdiRS9AYydjQlHa6jb51S0sKXzTVYELCJZAXP-ALS_whAh_ojFeltKLKzOC9iYodyAAwq4QnclbL3LKvBeVtCEfS9WjyYzyHDhCngJ-JrIwW",
    "sid": "6068aec4fd4fc47b623bceaf1f2c8f6b",
    "code": 435
}
```

I am not sure what did I do wrong ?

My streaming is running on a android device , only one broadcaster no audience
And I called the API from postman

I have double checked every parameter

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you are passing the authentication token in the request body of start API.

Here is sample

```
{
   "cname":"{{AccessChannel}}",
   "uid":"{{RecordingUID}}",
   "clientRequest":{
      "token": "<place token here>",
      "recordingConfig":{
         "maxIdleTime":300,
         "streamTypes":2,
         "channelType":1,
         "videoStreamType":0,
         "transcodingConfig":{
            "height":640,
            "width":360,
            "bitrate":500,
            "fps":15,
            "mixedVideoLayout":1,
            "backgroundColor":"#FF0000"
         },
         "subscribeVideoUids":[
            "123",
            "456"
         ],
         "subscribeAudioUids":[
            "123",
            "456"
         ],
         "subscribeUidGroup":0
      },
      "storageConfig":{
         "vendor":1,
         "region":0,
         "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
         "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
         "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}",
         "fileNamePrefix":[
            "directory1",
            "directory2"
         ]
      },
      "recordingFileConfig":{
         "avFileType":[
            "hls"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```